# Can I use elastic beanstalk if I am a lightsail user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-lightsail

Can I use elastic beanstalk if I am a light sail user. After creating an instance I can't find an instance in ec2>instance

Answer (score 0):

Lightsail instances don't show up in EC2. They are managed through a stand alone interface. https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com